# Can somebody describe the frame dragging around Sagittarius A at the center of our galaxy?

Tags: black-holes, milky-way, frame-dragging

I need to be able to visualize it, specifically the number of turns and how it relates to the horizons in the black hole and what would happen to something falling in also described. Has anyone ever tried to do this? I literally cannot find anything on this and I asked a Nobel prize laureate who also didn’t know ‍♀️

Comment: Do you want to know what frame dragging would look like with SgA*'s known parameters, or do you want observational details of observed frame dragging there?

Comment: The spin of this black hole is not really known. The only estimate I could [find](http://www.sci-news.com/astronomy/sagittarius-a-spin-08993.html) is that it is less than 1/10 of the maximal value. So no one is going to be able to *precisely* describe the amount of frame-dragging it causes. I recommend learning about frame-dragging in general rather than focusing on Sag A*.